# How to subtract to array objects?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an appplication in which i need timestamp.I have two arrays with string objects containing hours,minutes and seconds and i need to subtract those and put them in third arrays as hours,minutes and seconds as three objects.

example:

```
arr1=[9,10,22]
arr2=[10,12,42];
```

so the answer should be

```
arr3=[1,2,22]
```

and i need to put this array objects in a string separated by `' :'`

Kindly help.

Comment: do you want simple subtraction or time subtraction eg if the seconds difference is negative it effects the minute variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
NSMutableArray *arr3 = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<[arr1 count];i++)
{
  [arr3 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[arr2 objectAtIndex:i]integerValue]-[[arr1 objectAtIndex:i]integerValue]]];
}

NSString *combinedStr = [arr3 componentsJoinedByString:@":"];
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
NSMutableArray * arr3=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[arr3 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]integerValue]-[[arr1 objectAtIndex:0]integerValue]]];

[arr3 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[arr2 objectAtIndex:1]integerValue]-[[arr1 objectAtIndex:1]integerValue]]];

[arr3 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[arr2 objectAtIndex:2]integerValue]-[[arr1 objectAtIndex:2]integerValue]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
NSMutableArray *arr3=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [arr3 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]intValue]-[[arr1 objectAtIndex:0]intValue]]];
    [arr3 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[arr2 objectAtIndex:1]intValue]-[[arr1 objectAtIndex:1]intValue]]];
    [arr3 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[arr2 objectAtIndex:2]intValue]-[[arr1 objectAtIndex:2]intValue]]];
```